# Principal matrix, Ramsey theorem

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

**Question:**

Let m be given. Show that if n is large enough, then every n-by-n 0, 1-matrix has a
principal submatrix of size m in which all elements above the diagonal are the same, and all
elements below the diagonal are the same.

([How can we apply Ramsey's theorem to solve this problem on matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842863/how-can-we-apply-ramseys-theorem-to-solve-this-problem-on-matrices) - this is the same question, I have a bit of a different approach to solving this and I was wondering if this is correct as well, (or not?):

**My approach:**
We define a "special" matrix like this A s.t.
$  a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 \text { if $i\ne j \land (u_i,u_j$) is blue} \\
1 \text { if $i\ne j \land (u_j, u_i$) is red}  \\ 0 \text{ if $i=j$} \end{cases}$
This matrix will indeed translate any clique to a 0-1 matrix as desired (with all equal values above and below the diagonal). Now all we need to show is that for every graph, a clique of size m exists (=a sub matrix of this design). But from Ramsey's theorem for some n we have: $R(m,m)=n<\infty$ therefore any large enough matrix (=some translation of any large enough graph) will have such a sub matrix.